# excel - nested if condition formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I was just wondering if this is the proper way to nest this many conditions. It does work, just looks like it could be written simpler.

```
=IF(H13>0,IF(H14>0,IF(H15>0,IF(H16>0,IF(H17>0,IF(H18>0,IF(H19>0,"Yes","No"),"No"),"No"),"No"),"No"),"No"),"No")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above formula can be written as

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H13:H19,">0")=7,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: This is perfect, nice simple, and I understand it =) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AND`

```
=IF(AND(H13>0,H14>0,H15>0,H16>0,H17>0,H18>0,H19>0),"Yes","No")
```

Also use OR

```
=IF(OR(H13<=0,H14<=0,H15<=0,H16<=0,H17<=0,H18<=0,H19<=0),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: not quite as simplified as I was looking for, but good to know.  Thank you.